# Рекурсивный обход в глубину

Tags: c

Дан неориентированный граф без циклов и петель. Необходимо вывести все вершины графа при обходе в глубину.
Не совсем понимаю в чем заключается ошибка, программа выводит только первую вершину и заканчивает свою работу.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void dfsIn(int v, int*used, int n, int mat[n][n]) {
    int next;
    used[v] == 1;
    printf ("%d\n", v);
        for(next = 0; next < n; next++)
            if( mat[v][next] == 1 && used[next] == 0)
                return dfsIn(next, used, n, mat);
}
int main () {
    int n, m; //n - vertices, m - edges
    scanf ("%d %d", &n, &m);
    int i, j, k, l, a[n][n], used[n];
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            used[i] == 0;
            for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
                a[i][j] == 0;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            scanf ("%d %d", &k, &l);
            a[k-1][l-1] == 1;
            a[l-1][k-1] == 1;
        }
    dfsIn(1, used, n, a); 
}
```

Comment: Ошибка тут: `return dfsIn`. Их даже две.

Comment: Вот так `if( mat[v][next] == 1)` сравнение правильное, а это присваивание `used[v] == 1;` - неправильно. Нужно писать с одним равно `used[v]` **=** `1;`

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а как правильно, просто dfsIn ?

Comment: Да. Как компилятор пропустил такой код? Или вы не смотрите на предупреждения?

Comment: `used` на деревьях не нужен совсем. Это для циклических графов, а для дерева достаточно передавать dfsIn значение "предыдущая вершина".

Comment: Не проверять результат `scanf` - очень в стиле "вперед к результату, все ошибки не важны".

Comment: Согласен с @AlexGlebe, у вас много присвоений заменены на сравнения. Компилятор сыплет предупреждения простынями.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy странно, компилятор не выдает ни одного предупреждения

Comment: @kontsev_, очень хорошая практика использовать компилятор с максимально высоким уровнем проверок и всегда исправлять их все. Вы учитесь программировать, а это самый быстрый способ не писать заведомо не рабочий код. C - язык в котором нет никаких средств защиты. Лестница без перил.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy какой ресурс вы бы могли посоветовать по данной теме (Рекурсивный обход в глубину), так как все равно не понимаю как правильно написать программу

Comment: Вторая вещь: проходите код в отладчике по шагам. "Написал - работает" в С не работает. Или вы железно уверены в коде, или вы его проверили вдоль и поперек.

Answer (score 0):

Вот как выглядит результат компиляции вашего кода:

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror dfs.c 
> dfs.c: In function ‘dfsIn’:
> dfs.c:6:13: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
>     6 |     used[v] == 1;
>       |     ~~~~~~~~^~~~
> dfs.c:10:24: error: ISO C forbids ‘return’ with expression, in function returning void [-Werror=pedantic]
>    10 |                 return dfsIn(next, used, n, mat);
>       |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> dfs.c:4:6: note: declared here
>     4 | void dfsIn(int v, int*used, int n, int mat[n][n]) {
>       |      ^~~~~
> dfs.c: In function ‘main’:
> dfs.c:17:21: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
>    17 |             used[i] == 0;
>       |             ~~~~~~~~^~~~
> dfs.c:19:25: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
>    19 |                 a[i][j] == 0;
>       |                 ~~~~~~~~^~~~
> dfs.c:23:25: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
>    23 |             a[k-1][l-1] == 1;
>       |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
> dfs.c:24:25: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
>    24 |             a[l-1][k-1] == 1;
>       |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
> cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
> ```

Исправив указанные ошибки, вы получите работающую программу. Хотя возможности для улучшения ещё будут.